# Should free() been called after longjmp()?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free, setjmp

In this simple code should I take care about memory freeing in default case to escape from memory leak or can I use allocated memory? Does longjmp also revert memory allocations?

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv)
{
jmp_buf jmpbuf;

int *p=NULL;

switch(setjmp(jmpbuf)){
case 0:
    p=(int *) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    printf("%p\n",p);
    longjmp(jmpbuf,1);
    break;
default:
    printf("%p\n",p);
    free(p);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialise `p = NULL` to be sure a call to `free()` will not fail, even is `p = malloc(...)` had never been called.

Comment: I've corrected declaration so p is initialized to NULL. On first attempt it's always case 0 and allocated address is printed, but on second attempt still p points to the old allocated location instead of NULL. I've tried also to move int *p=NULL between switch and case 0 statements. So is it okay to call free on it? Should not it be NULL? I'm testing it with gcc 4.8.

Comment: As far as I understand in registers are stored addresses where actual values are stored, and recovering registers does not revert values in memory. How can someone be sure that values are not stored in registers instead of memory?

Comment: `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `longjmp` does not revert dynamic memory allocations.

Answer (score 2):

[longjmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) will restore the *values* of the variables "on the stack" (in this case "p").  However, there are two problems with that in this example:

- in the default case, p has not been assigned a value, and freeing it would be an error.
- if the example showed p being allocated an example, the memory leak still would not be fixed, because longjmp cannot do anything about that.

Comment: "in the default case, p has not been assigned a value, and freeing it would be an error." But it's guaranteed that setjmp() will return 0 when called directly so when we reach default case via `longjmp` the memory has already been allocated (`case 0` assuming malloc succeeded) so why not free that memory as done in the posted code?

Comment: The only modification I'll suggest is to declare `p` as `volatile int *p = NULL;` since we're modifying `p` after `setjmp` and before calling `longjmp()`

Answer (score 0):

`longjmp()` *will not* deallocate the memory for you, so you'll have to `free()` it manually. This is one of the complications with using `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` to escape deep call stacks, since you have to worry about cleaning up the resources used by any of the parent functions. Note that in your example, you **must** declare `p` as [`volatile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)) (`int *volatile p = NULL;`) to prevent it from potentially getting clobbered by `longjmp()`, since it's modified after the `setjmp()` call (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996825/why-volatile-works-for-setjmp-longjmp) for an explanation).

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly valid program except:

1. not declaring `p` as `volatile` and
2. declaring `argv` as `char *`.

And yes, `free()` needs to be called after `longjmp()` if the memory has been allocated before `longjmp()`.

Since it's guaranteed that the return value of `setjmp` will be `0` on direct execution, we can be sure that memory **will be** allocated via `case 0`.

And, if a local variable needs to be changed after `setjmp()` and before calling `longjmp` then you need to declare it as `volatile` to ask compiler to not to optimize and store in registers but to store/load from stack only.

Why? Because when `longjmp` loads the saved environment it loads program counter, stack pointer and values in registers saved at the time of direct `setjmp()` call. If compiler optimizes and stores the variable in register after the `setjmp()` call then `longjmp` can't access that value since what it has is register values *at the time* of `setjmp` call. So we ask compiler to not to save in registers but to save/load from stack only. And since `longjmp` has stack pointer we get the latest values of accessible variables from the stack.

Updated code:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    jmp_buf jmpbuf;
    volatile int *p;

    switch (setjmp(jmpbuf)) {
        case 0:
            p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
            printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);
            longjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);
            free((void *)p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```